# To francophone users: would you, please, give me feedback on my covering letter?

Tags: feedback, recommendations

Hi everyone, I just came across a job offer at Dubbing Brothers and I'm all shaking to the idea of convincing them it's a job for me! I'm not asking you for help with the content, just tell me if there's anything sticking out that shouldn't be... please :)

https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1ODv16e3eidnWIpVB_6eiMpLHydUrjYZjDsrc9jAz3yo&hl=en&authkey=CKLOi48M

I'm still editing it at the moment but this version is already well advanced. So please feel free to have a look at it and tell me whether you're convinced or not. The motivation is here (with me), I just need to get it across!

Thanks a lot!

PS: please forgive my grammar, I usually am a champion at it but I'm working on a QWERTY keyboard so I'll have to do a pass with the character map to correct all the accents issues. Let's focus on the content :)

Comment: Also, do you reckon I should write it by hand?

Comment: nah, but who knows who the recipient is. 

Answer (score 2):

Hi Justin, there are a few "fautes de conjugaison" in your letter... I just copy-paste the good one if you don't mind.

"Dubbing Brothers est un studio où je pourrai**S** exprimer mes qualités organisationnelles et mes connaissances techniques au service d’une équipe expérimentée. Vous m’offrir**I**ez l’opportunité d’un premier contact avec l’industrie du cinéma que j’investirai**S** pleinement. Si vous considérez ma candidature pour ce poste, je serai**S** heureux de me montrer à la hauteur de votre confiance. Je me tiens à votre disposition pour tout renseignement supplémentaire. Je vous prie de croire, Madame, en l’expression de mes sincères salutations.

Besides, I know them quite good, and you could also say how much you like to work with actors and how sound editing is important to you in the final quality of a project.

Good luck.

Sam

Comment: Thanks Sam, however these are not really mistakes. I was intentionally using the future tense. I understand it is not how it should be done so I'll change it back. I appreciate the little tips :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems spot on to me! Well done. If you are aiming to work your way up to becoming a sound editor (as you mention) but within the company rather than in general, it might be worth adding a little on your DAW or general sound software proficiencies. Also a bit on your practical experience if you have. Not sure though, up to you.

I wish you all the best with your application! They'd be stupid not to hire you :-)

Comment: Thanks Andrew that's much appreciated! I'm keeping all the ideas but reorganizing it slightly to make it more readable, as I was told by another user (directly on Google Doc's chat) that it was not always easy to read. I'm guessing from the time of your answer that you saw the Being Reworked version, which means I'm moving the right way :)